# Тэги Section/Article

Tags: html, html5, вёрстка

С точки зрения семантики, верно ли будет такое написание? В двух тегах article будет превьюха статьи с картинкой, в третьем - видео.

```
<main>
<aside>
...
</aside>
<section>
    <article>
    ...
    </article>
    <article>
    ...
    </article>

    <article>
    ...
    </article>
</section>
```

</main>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал не плодить однотипные теги, а-ля `<div>`, а посмотреть в сторону [header](http://htmlbook.ru/html/header), [footer](http://htmlbook.ru/html/footer), [figure](http://htmlbook.ru/html/figure) и [figcaption](http://htmlbook.ru/html/figcaption).

Собственно, я бы сделал примерно [такую](http://risto.beska.ru/phptest/blogtemp.html) структуру:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <style>
            .preview img {
                float: left; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <section>
                <header>
                    <h2><!-- Заголовок статьи --></h2>
                    <figure class="preview">
                        <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-yNPjT3pA324/Tnnq_BQdeMI/AAAAAAAAAF4/dhBPZCe-2Ek/s1600/Canary-In-A-Coal-Mine.jpg" alt="" />
                        <figcaption>
                            <!-- Краткая версия статьи -->  
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </header>
                <article>
                    <!-- Текст статьи -->
                </article>
                <footer><!-- Ссылка на источник, метки, etc. --></footer>
            </section>
            <section>
                ...
            </section>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Судя по этой статье http://webhitech.ru/notes/div-section-article/ , такое вложение приемлемо. Figure и figcaption в этой ситуации не подойдут. 
Как мне кажется, article отлично смотрится для превью постов.
Надеюсь услышать  и мнения остальных)

Comment: @opticmistic, ещё как подойдут!) Обновил ответ, добавил пример разметки и ссылку на её реализацию. Кстати, у раздела (section) могут быть свои шапка (header) и подвал (footer), что я тоже использовал. За ссылку спасибо.